# Cannot load data table with JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am trying to load JSON into a jQuery data table.

When firing the `change` event, using the below method, I can return to the console the exact same data I need to load in the data table:

```
 $('#serviceload').change(function()
 {
   var page = $('#serviceload').val();

   $.ajax({
     "type": 'POST',
     "url": 'api/service_teus.php',
     "data": {page:page},
     //"dataType": 'json',
     "success": function(data){
        console.log('success', data);
     },
     "error": function(msg){
        console.log('fail', msg);
     }
   });
 });
```

Now when I change the code above to include the data table, this is where I'm stuck:

```
 $('#serviceload').change(function()
 {
   var page = $('#serviceload').val();

   var $dataTable = $('#example1').DataTable({
     "ajax":{
       "url": 'api/service_teus.php',
       "data": {page:page},
       "dataType": 'json',
       "success": function(data){
         console.log('success', data);
        },
       "error": function(msg){
         console.log('fail', msg);
        }
      }
 });
```

Using the above method, the console returns an array of objects, but doesn't load the data table.

Answering this question will actually help me answer another question I posted.

Comment: checking the basics here: does your response return `json`? can you tell us what `data` looks like ? (i.e. the output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` )

Comment: @ochi Adding your suggestion to the console.log, I can get the data I need in the datatable to show in the console.  It looks similar to this:   [{"SERVICE":"aName","SIZE_TYPE":"20BK","TEUS":"5.0","ADD_DATE":"2016-03-31 00:00:00","ADD_USER":"usa.admin","MOD_DATE":"2016-04-11 08:50:34","MOD_USER":"usa.admin"},{...}]

Comment: This is not the expected datasource for the datatable. your datasource needs to be in the form {"data": [[],[],[]...]}. Check the documentation for a better example: https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used my answer from this page:  [Load JQUERY DATATABLE on CHANGE event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36625733/load-jquery-datatable-on-change-event)

And I was able to finally move on.

Answer (score 3):

Your dataTable is likely being generated with the ajax promise and not the returned data. Generate the datatable inside your success function instead of using the entire ajax statement.

Something like this.

```
$('#serviceload').change(function()
 {
   var page = $('#serviceload').val();

   $.ajax({
     "type": 'POST',
     "url": 'api/service_teus.php',
     "data": {page:page},
     "dataType": 'json',
     "success": function(data){
        console.log('success', data);
        $dataTable = $('#example1').DataTable(data);
     },
     "error": function(msg){
        console.log('fail', msg);
     }
   });
 });
```

Comment: Thank you, sir.  I am testing your suggestion.  I will get back to you asap.

Comment: I attempted your code, made a few changes, primarily in the "success" function, I updated your suggestion to read:  $dataTable = $('#example1').DataTable(data);  ---  With this, I am able to return to at least return to the console an array of objects.  Within those objects is the data I need, but I just cannot get it to print to the datatable.  Still testing...